# Angular show element based on height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Currently I have a paragraph that gets shortened/lengthened based on the max height. I was wondering if there was a way that I could show/hide the anchor element if the height is over a certain amount.
Essentially  I only want to show the "more..." if it's needed.

```js
$scope.hidden = true;
```

```css
    .__Description {
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    .less {
      max-height: 160px;
 
    }
```

```html
<div class="__Description">
     <div class="__contents" ng-class="{less: hidden}">
      <div data-ng-bind-html="program.Description"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <a ng-click="hidden = !hidden">{{hidden? 'More...' : 'Less...'}}</a>
```

Comment: how is the content being loaded into the <div>? Is it loaded dynamically, via AJAX, or only on first load?

Comment: Did you consider showing 'more...' depending on the description characters length? namely, <a ng-show="program.Description.length > 200" ng-click="hidden =!hidden"> .... </a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap the content and the read more in a directive.

The directive would watch for the content height, and then toggle a property on the scope.

Here is pseudo code for the general idea. (plunker link below)
To make the code more suitable for your needs I need more info

```
<program-description>
<div class="__programDescription">
    <div class="__contents" ng-class="{less: hidden}">
        <div data-ng-bind-html="program.Description"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</program-description>


angular.module('myApp').directive('programDescription', function(){

    return {

         restrict: 'A',
         transclude: true, 
         template: '<div><div ng-transclude></div> <a ng-show="showToggle">{{ toggleText }}</a></div>',
         link: function( scope, element, attrs ){
               var limit = attrs.limit  ? parseInt(attrs.limit,10) : 200; // default to 200px
               scope.$watch(function(){
                   return element.find('.__programDescription').height();
               }, function(if (newValue > limit){
                   scope.showToggle = true;
               });

               .. some more code to handle more/less clicks.. 

         }
     }

})
```

a working plunker is available at: http://plnkr.co/edit/Sm393HAzTRp8wqEPNkdg?p=preview

Comment: Isn't this a bit overkill for just showing 'Less' or 'More' based on the length of the description?

Comment: @MHakvoort depends on the scenario. I like to put the extra mile and get reusable component and share it in the community.

Comment: Ah, I now see your take on his 'problem'. Good answer, gonna upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can show this based on the **length** of your description.

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The length property returns the length of a string (number of characters).
>
> The length of an empty string is 0.

For example:

```
<a href="#" ng-show="program.Description.length < 1000">More...</a>
```

Edit:

As @Andrew Tomlinson mentioned, you can keep the logic in 1 sentence for example like this:

```
<a href="#"> (program.Description.length < 1000) ? 'More...' : 'Less...'</a>
```

Comment: I like the idea of using the length instead of the max height (because max height actually changes based on the sate of `hidden`). But I think the idea is to keep the functionality of the 'More/Less' anchor the same and simply hide it if the length of the description is short enough to fit inside the container to begin with. Maybe something like `<a ng-hide="program.Description.length < 1000" ng-click="hidden = !hidden">{{hidden? 'More...' : 'Less...'}}</a>` would do it?

Comment: Well if i use .length i would have to define length in programs no?

Comment: `length` is a property of the javascript String object, so you shouldn't have to define it separately in your program. It's the number of characters that make up the string.

Comment: This solution won't work.. though you display less content, the length of the string is the same.. you cannot rely on the length.